# Getting the indices of the max value of each connected component

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, matrix, computer-vision

Given an image `img`, I get the connected components in Matlab with `bwconncomp`. From the connected components returned, I can get the max value of each component. But, how do I get the index of the max value? I want to know where the max value actually occurs in the image.

Here's the pseudocode for what I have so far:

```
 cc = bwconncomp(img)
 % iterate through the length(cc.PixelIdxList)
      value(it) = max(cc.PixelIdxList{:,it})
      x(it) = ?
      y(it) = ?
```

How do I get `x` and `y`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
 ind(it) = max(cc.PixelIdxList{:,it})
 [x(it),y(it)] = ind2sub(size(img),ind(it))
```

In fact [`PixelIdxList`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwconncomp.html#output_argument_CC) gives you the linear index of the pixel, and not its value, and you can use [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to convert it to subscript index.

To get the value itself type:

```
value(it) = img(ind(it));
```

Comment: This is perfect--exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!